# Is 'simplify something to' correct (for example in the context of maths)?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

My question concerns the preposition that is used with the word 'simplify'.

I am unsure which of the following is correct:

'By substitution, the problem is simplified to a system of linear equations.'

or

'By substitution, the problem is simplified into a system of linear equations.'

Or is neither of them correct?

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Simplify-Math-Expressions

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I only found example sentences there that are of the form '...simplify the equation...'. I am wondering about the case when one thing gets simplified/transformed into another thing (or does this not work with 'simplify')?

Comment: You can use either _to_ or _into_ (just as you can say _change to_ or _change into_).

Comment: You did not read far enough:"we can write the expression as (2(x2 + 2x + 3))/2 and thus simplify to x2 + 2x + 3". When you get to a page, you can search again using the find function.

Comment: I would not say in math, simplify into.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, so I guess I will just stick with 'to'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question that does not have a good answer.

Both the examples you cite will be understood by mathematicians and their students. Both are ugly. I won't venture to assert that either is wrong or right.

When in a textbooks or on an exam you are  asked to simplify some mathematical expression it's usually assumed that you know the form expected for a correct answer. (If the target expression was a set of linear equations the instructions would probably not ask you to simplify to get there.)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900917/is-there-any-official-specific-convention-that-defines-whether-an-expression-is/3901091#3901091